# Action listener not working

Tags: java, swing, action, actionlistener

I am trying to implement an ActionListener for a JComboBoxe so that when an item in the list is selected, and the ok jbutton clicked, I want it to appear in a new gui I have defined with a textfield in it therefore when an item is selected from the combobox it will appear in the textfield of the gui and the details of which item is selected.

This example shows one combobox, but I have 6 in total.

```
jComboBox4.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
jComboBox4.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jComboBox4MouseClicked(evt);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want something to happen when the JButton is clicked, then attach your ActionListener to the JButton, not to the JComboBox.

Comment: Inside the `actionPerformed(...)` method of the `JButton(OK Button)`, simply use `jComboBox4.getSelectedItem() and so on for others` and simply pass it, to be shown in other components, as the need be :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help but this did not seem to work i tried them as directed in both places Jbutton 1 is the main button or otherwords the (Ok button

Comment: private void jComboBox4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jComboBox4.getSelectedItem() then here

Comment: private void jComboBox4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
       jComboBox4.getSelectedItem()

Comment: rivate void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      private void jComboBox4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
       jComboBox4.getSelectedItem()

Comment: please edit your question with additional information instead of trying to do do so in a comment - it's barely readable in the latter :-)

Comment: Did you write the code in your snippet or was it generated by a GUI builder? The reason I ask is because if you can edit it directly, answering your question will be a little easier. However, if it is generated by a GUI, you will have to jump through a few hoops. Either way, you will need to add an `ActionListener` rather than a `MouseListener` to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First add a `ActionListener` to the required button

```
// When the button is clicked this is called...
public class ButtonActionListener extends ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Object value = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        // check for null value
        // do what ever it is you want to do after that...            
    }
}
```

If you want to monitor changes to the ComboBox, you have a number of choices, the easiest is the ActionListener

```
// When the button is clicked this is called...
public class ComboBixActionListener extends ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Object value = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        // The combo box value has changed, maybe update the text field???
    }
}
```

Comment: again many thanks but still cant get it no matter were i put it it will not change when item clicked on combobox into the textfield in the details gui is is something to do with private or public new to netbeans trying to find my feet with it